Increase SVG size in make4ht
I would like to increase the default scale of dvisvgm as invoked from the make4ht scripts. Is there a way to pass the "scale" option to dvisvgm_hashes from the command line?
Thanks,
Allen

You can configure most extensions or filters using the filter_settings command. You can see list of settings for dvisvgm_hashes extension here. You can use the scale option for scaling. Default value is 1.15. Save this code as build.lua:
filter_settings "dvisvgm_hashes" {
  scale= 1.6
}

Remove all SVG files to force their regeneration, and compile using:
$ make4ht -e build.lua -f html5+dvisvgm_hashes sample.tex

This is how it looks with a small sample:


Thanks! That's just what I needed.
